# Problems displaying LOESS regression line and confidence interval

Tags: r, regression, loess

I am having some issues trying to compete a LOESS regression with a data set. I have been able to properly create the line, but I am unable to get it to plot correctly.

I ran through the data like this.

```
animals.lo <- loess(X15p5 ~ Period, animals, weights = n.15p5)    
animals.lo    
summary(animals.lo)    
plot(X15p5~ Period, animals)    
lines(animals$X15p5, animals.lo, col="red")
```

At this point I received an error

> "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ"

I searched around and read that this issue could be due to the points needing to be ordered, so I proceeded.

```
a <- order(animals$Period)    
lines(animals$X15p5[a], animals.lo$Period[a], col="red", lwd=3)
```

There were no errors at this point, but the LOESS line was still not showing up in the plot. The points were displayed correctly, but not the line.

This is similar to the data set I am using...

```
structure(list(Site = c("Cat", "Dog", "Bear", "Chicken", "Cow",
"Bird", "Tiger", "Lion", "Leopard", "Wolf", "Puppy", "Kitten", 
"Emu", "Ostrich", "Elephant", "Sheep", "Goat", "Fish", "Iguana", 
"Monkey", "Gorilla", "Baboon", "Lemming", "Mouse", "Rat", "Hamster", 
"Eagle", "Parrot", "Crow", "Dove", "Falcon", "Hawk", "Sparrow", 
"Kite", "Chimpanzee", "Giraffe", "Bear", "Donkey", "Mule", "Horse", 
"Zebra", "Ox", "Snake", "Cobra", "Iguana", "Lizard", "Fly", "Mosquito", 
"Llama", "Butterfly", "Moth", "Worm", "Centipede", "Unicorn", 
"Pegasus", "Griffin", "Ogre", "Monster", "Demon", "Witch", "Vampire", 
"Mummy", "Ghoul", "Zombie"), Region = c(6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 8L), Period = c(-2715, -3500, 
-3500, -4933.333333, -2715, -2715, -2715, -3500, -2715, -4350, 
-3500, -3500, -2950, -4350, -3650, -3500, -3500, -2715, -3650, 
-4350, -3500, -3500, -3400, -4350, -3500, -3500, -4350, -3900, 
-3808.333333, -4233.333333, -3500, -3900, -3958.333333, -3900, 
-3500, -3500, -3500, -2715, -3650, -2715, -2715, -2715, -2715, 
-3500, -2715, -2715, -3500, -4350, -3650, -3650, -4350, -5400, 
-3500, -3958.333333, -3400, -3400, -4350, -3600, -4350, -3650, 
-3500, -2715, -5400, -3500), Value = c(0.132625995, 0.163120567, 
0.228840125, 0.154931973, 0.110047847, 0.054347826, 0.188679245, 
0.245014245, 0.128378378, 0.021428571, 0.226277372, 0.176923077, 
0.104938272, 0.17659805, 0.143798024, 0.086956522, 0.0625, 0.160714286, 
0, 0.235588972, 0, 0, 0.208333333, 0.202247191, 0.364705882, 
0.174757282, 0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.184027778, 0.232876712, 0.160493827, 
0.74702381, 0.126984127, 0.080645161, 0.06557377, 0, 0.057692308, 
0.285714286, 0.489361702, 0.108695652, 0.377777778, 0, 0.522727273, 
0.024390244, 0.097560976, 0.275, 0, 0.0625, 0.255319149, 0.135135135, 
0.216216216, 0.222222222, 0.296296296, 0.222222222, 0.146341463, 
0.09375, 0.125, 0.041666667, 0.078947368, 0.2, 0.137931034, 0.571428571, 
0.142857143), Sample_size = c(188.5, 105.75, 79.75, 70, 52.25, 
46, 39.75, 39, 37, 35, 34.25, 32.5, 32.4, 30.76666667, 30.36666667, 
28.75, 28, 28, 28, 26.6, 25, 25, 24, 22.25, 21.25, 20.6, 20, 
20, 20, 19.2, 18.25, 18, 18, 16.8, 15.5, 15.25, 15, 13, 12.6, 
11.75, 11.5, 11.25, 11, 11, 10.25, 10.25, 10, 10, 9.6, 9.4, 9.25, 
9.25, 9, 9, 9, 8.2, 8, 8, 8, 7.6, 7.5, 7.25, 7, 7), Sample_sub = c(25, 
17.25, 18.25, 10.8452381, 5.75, 2.5, 7.5, 9.555555556, 4.75, 
0.75, 7.75, 5.75, 3.4, 5.433333333, 4.366666667, 2.5, 1.75, 4.5, 
0, 6.266666667, 0, 0, 5, 4.5, 7.75, 3.6, 0, 8, 2, 3.533333333, 
4.25, 2.888888889, 13.44642857, 2.133333333, 1.25, 1, 0, 0.75, 
3.6, 5.75, 1.25, 4.25, 0, 5.75, 0.25, 1, 2.75, 0, 0.6, 2.4, 1.25, 
2, 2, 2.666666667, 2, 1.2, 0.75, 1, 0.333333333, 0.6, 1.5, 1, 
4, 1)), .Names = c("Site", "Region", "Period", "Value", "Sample_size", 
"Sample_sub"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -64L))
```

I have been working for this a while and trying to read up as much as I can, but I haven't been able to make any additional headway. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Follow-up on adding confidence interval to plot**

I have been trying to add in confidence intervals following another example found on the site on this page [How to get the confidence intervals for LOWESS fit using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717930/how-to-get-the-confidence-intervals-for-lowess-fit-using-r) .

The example given on that page is:

```
plot(cars)
plx<-predict(loess(cars$dist ~ cars$speed), se=T)

lines(cars$speed,plx$fit)
lines(cars$speed,plx$fit - qt(0.975,plx$df)*plx$se, lty=2)
lines(cars$speed,plx$fit + qt(0.975,plx$df)*plx$se, lty=2)
```

I adapted that as this:

```
plot(X15p5 ~ Period, animals)
animals.lo2<-predict(loess(animals$X15p5 ~ animals$Period), se=T)
a <- order(animals$Period)
lines(animals$Period[a],animals.lo2$fit, col="red", lwd=3)
lines(animals$Period[a],animals.lo2$fit - qt(0.975,animals.lo2$df)*animals.lo2$se, lty=2)
lines(animals$Period[a],animals.lo2$fit + qt(0.975,animals.lo2$df)*animals.lo2$se, lty=2)
```

Although this does provide confidence intervals, the regression line is all wrong. I'm not sure if it is an issue with the `predict` function, or another issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry about that, the example wasn't the exact set I was using. the X15p5 is equivalent to Value, and the n.X15p5 is equivalent to Sample_size. Your explanation worked though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**correct code**

> I searched around and read that this issue could be due to the points needing to be ordered, so I proceeded.

No, no. The ordering issue is not related to the error you see. To overcome the error, You need to replace

```
lines(animals$X15p5, animals.lo, col="red")
```

with

```
lines(animals$Period, animals.lo$fitted, col="red")
```

Here are reasons:

1. `loess` returns a list of objects, not a single vector. See `str(animals.lo)` or `names(animals.lo)`.
2. why do you use `animals$X15p5` as x-axis? You fit your model: `X15p5 ~ Period`, so x-axis should be `Period`.

**about reordering**

You need to do ordering, because by default, R lines up points in order. Take this as an example:

```
set.seed(0); x <- runif(100, 0, 10)  ## x is not in order
set.seed(1); y <- sqrt(x)  ## plot curve y = sqrt(x)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(x, y, type = "l")  ## this is a mess!!
reorder <- order(x)
plot(x[reorder], y[reorder], type = "l")  ## this is nice
```

[image: foo]

Similarly, do:

```
a <- order(animals$Period)    
lines(animals$Period[a], animals.lo$fitted[a], col="red", lwd=3)
```

---

**follow-up on confidence interval**

Try this:

```
plot(X15p5 ~ Period, animals)
animals.lo <- loess(X15p5 ~ Period, animals)
pred <- predict(animals.lo, se = TRUE)
a <- order(animals$Period)
lines(animals$Period[a], pred$fit[a], col="red", lwd=3)
lines(animals$Period[a], pred$fit[a] - qt(0.975, pred$df)*pred$se[a],lty=2)
lines(animals$Period[a], pred$fit[a] - qt(0.975, pred$df)*pred$se[a],lty=2)
```

You forgot about reordering again. You need to reorder both fitted values, as well as standard errors.

Now, the `dist ~ speed` model for `cars` data has no need for reordering. Because:

```
is.unsorted(cars$speed)  ## FALSE
```

Yes, data are already sorted there.

Note I have made two other changes to your code:

1. I have separated `loess` call and `predict` call; Maybe you don't need to do this, but it is generally a good habit to separate model fitting and model prediction, and keeps a copy of both objects.
2. I have changed `loess(animals$X15p5 ~ animals$Period)` to `loess(X15p5 ~ Period, animals)`. It is a bad habit to use `$` sign in specifying model formula. I have another answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37307270/4891738 showing the draw back of such style. You can read on the "update" section over there. I have used the `glm` as an example, but for `lm`, `glm`, `loess`, things are the same.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much. LOESS can be used in a lot of different ways, and explanations don't always fit with the way people intend to use them. Thank you very very much for not only the correct code, but the explanation as well!

Comment: Sorry to ask one additional follow-up, but I would like to add in confidence intervals as well. I had seen that some reccommended using the LOESS and predict function, but when I ran the code similarly to the example, the intial LOESS curve was quite different. The example used is as follows:  ---  plot(cars)
plx<-predict(loess(cars$dist ~ cars$speed), se=T)

lines(cars$speed,plx$fit)
lines(cars$speed,plx$fit - qt(0.975,plx$df)*plx$se, lty=2)
lines(cars$speed,plx$fit + qt(0.975,plx$df)*plx$se, lty=2)

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. I updated the post with the other suggested code and how I adapted it to my data set. Again, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The code works perfectly. I've really been enjoying working with R, but the learning curve is a bit steep and the answers are not always obvious or easy to find at first. Figuring this out and getting it to work is a huge relief. Thanks again for all of your help, as well as the pointers on "best practices" in using R.

Comment: LOL, only 7 more to go. When I get there I will definitely come back and update with an upvote!