# Messy plot when plotting predictions of a polynomial regression using lm() in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, lm

I am building a quadratic model with lm in R:

```
y <- data[[1]]
x <- data[[2]]
x2 <- x^2

quadratic.model = lm(y ~ x + x2)
```

Now I want to display both the predicted values and the actual values on a plot. I tried this:

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(y~x)
P <- predict(quadratic.model)
lines(x, P)
```

but the line comes up all squiggely. Maybe it has to do with the fact that it's quadratic? Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to sort the predicted data by x prior to plotting it.

Comment: Use `curve`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37389707/1412059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `order()`:

```
P <- predict(quadratic.model)
plot(y~x)
reorder <- order(x)
lines(x[reorder], P[reorder])
```

My answer here is related: [Problems displaying LOESS regression line and confidence interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37500120/4891738)